# Intellij not showing source of dependencies but always showing decompiled classes from jars in .m2

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

This issue started recently with upgrade of IntelliJ to 2021.1.2. I have multiple java maven modules in one of my project in IntelliJ. Some of the maven modules depends on other modules. When I want to view implementations of any api e.g. (Option+Command+B), it opens the decompiled .class files from the jar in my .m2 directory. Even though source of class is right there in my project. Earlier if I have imported source code of dependency module, then it will open java source file. If I have not imported dependency, only then it used to open decompiled class.

Any help appreciated, what to do so that IntelliJ first check existing source in project. and then open .java files from source instead of decompiled .class file from .m2 directory.

Comment: Make sure that <Module source> entry is the first one in the table at Dependencies tab of each module (Project Structure dialog).